# How do I open a the folder where an image is located from my Xamarin Android Application?

Tags: android, directory, contextmenu

I have tried looking almost everywhere on how to open the parent folder of a child image displayed in my app with no success. Am debugging my Android Application to a device running ***Android API level 29***. The inbuilt samsung File Manager has a menu item for navigating to the source folder of any file and that is why I believe there is a way to tell the App to open the location of the image displayed on my ImageSwitcher object. The app has a context menu with a ***Open Source Folder*** menu item for opening the source folder of the image, the code to do that is the problem...

***Code***

```
 public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
             case Resource.Id.image_folder:
                    try
                    {
                       //I tried this inbuild dotnet method but it does not work
                        string file_path = new Java.IO.File(files[index]).AbsolutePath;
                        DirectoryInfo info= new DirectoryInfo(file_path);
                        info.MoveTo(new Java.IO.File(file_path).Parent);
                        
                    }catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder mybuilder= new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        mybuilder.SetTitle("Exception");
                        mybuilder.SetMessage(ex.Message);
                        mybuilder.Show();
                    }
                    break;
            }
         }
```

Code below shows how I obtained the path to the ImageSwicther currentl image.

```
 void read_images()
        {
            //access the application's directory
            Java.IO.File original_file = (Application.GetExternalFilesDir(null));

            //check if the file is read only
            if (original_file.CanRead())
            {
                //Toast.MakeText(this, "This folder can be read", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            if (original_file.Exists() && original_file.IsDirectory)
            {
                try
                {
                    //make sure the file is an image file
                    //apply the code for image mime type extensions
                    
                   files = Directory.GetFiles(original_file.AbsolutePath);
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                    {
                        //delete any file that does not end with an image format
                        if (files[i].EndsWith("jpg") == false || files[i].EndsWith("png") == false)
                        {
                            Directory.Delete(files[i]);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alert.SetTitle("File Read Exception");
                    alert.SetMessage(e.Message + "\n" + e.Data);
                    alert.Show();
                }
                // Toast.MakeText(this, "File exists",ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Now that the I have the paths to the images in a string array, all I do is use an integer variable called ***index*** to switch the path and display it to the ImageSwitcher object when user swipes right or left like

```
                               //increment index for right swipe and decrement for left 
                                myswitcher.ClearAnimation();
                                myswitcher.SetInAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.slide_in_left);
                                myswitcher.SetOutAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.slide_out_left);
                                myswitcher.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(files[index])));
```

***NB:***
The ***files[index]*** is a string array containing paths of all the  images  displayed in the imageswitcher object.

Comment: You should start your post telling us how you obtained a path or uri to the image file. Tell path or uri. Give examples please.

Comment: The images are in the application external files directory,  I accessed the files from the path using C#, `Directory.GetFiles(string path);`

Comment: Repeat: `Tell path or uri. Give examples please. ` Any reason not to do so?

Comment: Edited the question to address your needs, I hope it helps Thank You

Comment: It helps. I see how you obtain paths. Not uries. Now you should give examples of some paths. I asked tha 22 hours ago and am still waiting..

Comment: So you start with a drectory and list the files in it and obtain their paths. (Meanwhile you delete all files which are not jpg's..). But anyhow. You then have paths to files and you wanna know which directory they are in?

Comment: I want the app to open the location with the inbuilt file explorer when user clicks the menu item , that's all

Comment: Start an intent to open the inbuilt file manager with the uri of the parent folder because I want now to scan images from the whole device now

Comment: Well then show us the uri of the parent folder. I'm puzzled as you work with paths and not with uries and you also don't react to the point.

Comment: The uri of the parent folder is `Uri.Parse(files[index]);`

Comment: That is no urie. That is a code statement. You should tell what that code statement returns. If it is an -external- files dir then which dir is it? What is path of the directory? `Log.d("alog", "value: " + Uri.Parse(files[index]).toString());` Tell us which value/path/urie you see in the logcat.

Comment: The default directory where the application stores the `cache` and `files` directory.

Comment: `Uri.FromFile(Application.GetExternalFilesDir(null))`